# Cloudera Quickstart gives error on VM Ware workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to set up the Cloudera CDH 4.7x on my windows machine that has VM Ware Workstation. I downloaded and unzipped all the files form this link

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-4-7-x.html

when i try to open the virtual machine in VM Ware workstation, i get an error pop up saying that

[image]

after i hit ok i get

[image]

i checked the settings for the virtual machine and they are

[image]

can someone please advise how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bits of version data virtual hardware version is the only one exposed in the GUI, likely this error is being thrown because the .config version (one of the non-exposed ones) is too new (higher integer value). This configuration file generation version is used as a hint to the internal parser, with successfully parsed lines eventually resulting in DICT entries if you are examining the vmware.log file.

Although not officially supported, you can *sometimes* simply decrement the .config value if the VM in question has a backwards compatible overall configuration. The .vmx file is structured plaintext, be careful not to change line-ending types (DOS, Unix, etc...).

Comment: thanks. would it help if i upgrade the vmware workstation version ?

Comment: What I suggested is one possibility. Amending your original post (or reply) with the .config and vhw.version values are, along with which version of VMware Workstation you’re running would help narrowing down the possibilities.